# PHP Join tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two tables:

**Table1** (sales)

- ID
- Ident
- Date
- Status

**Table2** (users)

- ID
- Ident
- Fullname
- Email

This is how I query the value:

```
<?php      
       $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE status='OK' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') DESC LIMIT 5";
           if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
                  $num_rows = 0;
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $num_rows++;
    
                      echo '<div class="my-box">';
                      echo "{$row['id']}";
                      echo "{$row['date']}";
                      echo "{$row['dbirth']}";
                      echo "{$row['email']}";
                      echo "{$row['ident']}";
                      echo '</div>';
                  }
                  $result->free();
              }
          ?>
```

Right now, it echo the `ident` for the row, but insted of showing the ident, I was it to display the `Fullname` that has the ident from Table2. I tried something like `SELECT * FROM sales LEFT JOIN users on sales.id = users.id`, but that doesn't gives me the `Fullname`. Any tips?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry That's not really was my question is about tho. Do you have a solution for the question?

Comment: _“but that doesn't gives me the Fullname”_ - what _does_ it give you then? Did you try that query in a frontend like phpMyAdmin first?

Comment: @CBroe It doesn't give me any value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL seems wrong.

When you join tables, do this way.

`SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;`

If you join tables right, you will be able to retrieve the 'Fullname' column.

Comment: Should I create this as a new query inside the one I already have, or replace it?

Comment: Rewrite your query because your code "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE status='OK' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE ... " will not join your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Ident field would be the **primary key** in the users table and **foreign key** in the sales table. If yes, this will return the desired result along with other listed fields from both tables.

```
SELECT sales.ID AS sales_ID,sales.Ident AS Identity,Date,Status,Fullname,Email FROM sales
INNER JOIN users ON sales.Ident = users.Ident
WHERE status='OK'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

If the date field is updated to date or datetime, simply use

```
ORDER BY DATE
```

For Better Database practises:

1. You need to change the date field data type to either *date* or *datetime*
2. You need to have an understanding of the Primary and Foreign key concept in RDBMS.
3. You need to learn **JOINS** in SQL

Comment: The date is currently `varchar`. Should I change to date(255) or datetime(255) or doesn't I need the `(255)` when using dates? And what is best, `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: if you want to keep track of dates, use date. If both, use datetime.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep track of both date and time, so then I'll just do `datetime` and no `datetime`? And one last question; Will the format still be same: `2020/08/03 15:27:34` ?

Comment: default SQL format is 2020-08-05 13:25:17 . You need to add date function to get the desired format. Link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp . If the answer helped, do support.